# Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined in python django template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I am getting an `Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined` error while trying to access a Python dictionary variable in a Django template.

I have tried escaping with `safe`, but it does not work:

```py
result = {'test1' : [{'var1': 'PLANNED', 'var2': 'description', 'var3': False},{'var1':'PLANNED', 'var2':'description', 'var3': True}], 'test2' : [{'var1': 'PLANNED', 'var2': 'description', 'var3': False},{'var1':'PLANNED', 'var2':'description', 'var3': True}]}
return render(request, 'users/team.html', {'team' : team, 'result ' : result })
```

I am accessing this in my HTML as below:

```
var params= {{result |safe}};
```

How can I assign this result to a variable in a Django template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're effectively writing `var params = ... False ...;` in JavaScript. However, `false` in JS is written as `false`, not `False`! Note the capitalization difference. This results in the JS VM trying to in part assign the value of the variable `False` to the variable `params`. Unfortunately, you haven't defined a variable called `False`! Hence, a `ReferenceError`.

One approach to fix this issue is chaining with the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter:

```
{{ result|json_script:"params-data" }}
<script>
    var value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('params-data').textContent);
</script>
```

Another approach is to manually encode/decode the `result` as JSON. e.g.

```
import json
return render(request, 'users/team.html', {'team' : team, 'result ' : json.dumps(result) })
```

and the

```
var params = JSON.parse('{{result|safe}}');
```

The first option is clearly preferable for its brevity and more straightforward nature.

Comment: In my case i don't want to convert the whole result to **lower** case. Also i cannot convert the bool on python side to lower case. Updated the code to show how i am passing data to frontend.

Comment: @shilpa ah, I misunderstood your issue. My answer has been updated.